# How many numbers will be showing a profit after betting 1 chip per number for N spins in the game of Roulette?

Tags: probability

There are 37 slots (numbers) on a roulette wheel and a hit on a number pays 35-1. Suppose there are 37 players each betting a different number. After N spins how many of these players will be in profit? I've written a computer simulation to get the answer but the average numbers vary significantly from run to run, so I would like an exact formula.